# conflicting id() function in my json search python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

**The problem:**

I am trying to search for a dns name in from my json value and return a device id.

The json export looks like this:

```
[{'id': 1,'dnsName': 'Server01.dnsexample.local'}]
```

When I try to write a for loop to find the dns name value and print out its corresponding device id, Python gets confused with is built id() function.

**Here is my code:**

```
find_deviceid = input("Enter System name or Dns Name of the computer you are trying to search: ")
for id, dnsName in napidevices[0].items():
    if dnsName == find_deviceid:
        print(id)
        print(dnsName)
```

**result:**

```
Enter System name or Dns Name of the computer you are trying to search: Server01.dnsexample.local

dnsName # this should say 1
Server01.dnsexample.local # this is correct
```

Any way to stop built this built in function from running instead of using the key value pair the from the dictionary?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: I think you've confused `dict.values()` with `dict.items()`. Also, shadowing built-in namespaces is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly get the value for the `id` key using:

```
napidevices[0].get('id')  # or napidevices[0]['id']
```

With `for id, dnsName in napidevices[0].items()`, you are iterating over a specific key, value pair of the dictionary. So, printing `id` will print the key i.e. `dnsName` in this case.

Also, not sure why you are explicitly iterating over just the first element of the list, you can iterate over the list to keep it generic as:

```
find_deviceid = 'Server01.dnsexample.local'
napidevices = [{'id': 1,'dnsName': 'Server01.dnsexample.local'}]
for device in napidevices:
    for idx, dnsName in device.items():
        if dnsName == find_deviceid:
            print(device.get('id'))
            print(dnsName)
```

You can also simplify the code to directly get the `dnsName` instead of iterating over key-value pairs using `items()` as:

```
for device in napidevices:
    dnsName = device.get('dnsName', None) # get the dnsName value
    if dnsName == find_deviceid:
        print(device.get('id'))
        print(dnsName)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You shouldn't use the same variable name with python built function**

python dict has a get method can meet your needs.

```py
find_deviceid = input("Enter System name or Dns Name of the computer you are trying to search: ")
find_deviceid = int(find_deviceid)
for item in napidevices:
    id_ = item.get('id')
    if id_ == find_deviceid:
        print(id_)
        print(dnsName)
```

By the way, your code can run in py2 or py3, but if you use py3, your input for find_deviceid is string type, you need turn it to int type manually.